# I can no longer ask questions, nor edit my posts or those of others

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, post-ban, edit-ban

Could someone please tell me why the editing of questions (mine and others) is disabled in my account?

It has been a very long time since I have been question banned, after your site told me that deleting questions again and again is not a good thing without any logical reason. I was paying attention to the Stack Overflow site very genuinely.

Because I didn't find any other option to ask my question, I asked this question here because you have closed 40% of my posts, which is creating a problem for me. I am unable to ask any questions and also not able to edit any question/answer.

I do realize all the mistakes I've made. But what should I do now?

Comment: So you're saying you're question-banned? Or are you experiencing technical difficulties? If it's the former, please read though this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: I already studied this link..i have already realized my mistakes.but there is no positive response from the site.Now, i am paying  genuine attention to the site..but they have banned my "Ask-question" and "edit power"..:(

Comment: Then you did not read that post well enough. The ban is not going to be lifted by anyone, nor does it time out. You will have to improve your existing content and contribute in other ways to gain reputation (through answering, making suggested edits, etc.)

Comment: Yes Bart, I had go through to all these(improve your existing content and contribute in other ways to gain reputation (through answering, making suggested edits, etc.)) but :(

Comment: The answer will still be "keep at it". Nobody will be able to tell you when your ban will be lifted. You will just have to keep working until it happens. It's an automatic system. I don't know your particular reputation or deletion history, but this might take quite some effort.

Comment: ok..thanks Bart for your suggestions..i will keep working until it happens..

Comment: And with regards to the suggested edits, take your time. Fix all there is to fix. And if something gets rejected, try to understand why that happens. Once you do, you are less likely to make the same mistake again and ultimately less likely to receive a temporary edit suspension.

Comment: @varsha upvoting your questions work .I was also facing the same problem

Comment: @Somnath "getting upvotes for your questions works", I assume?

Comment: @Somnath..It depends upon the viewers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggested edit ban is for having too many edits rejected recently; you had quite a few rejected on May 10th. (Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/users/889843/varsha?tab=activity&sort=suggestions ). Note that suggested edits should address multiple substantive problems with a post; suggestions to correct minor grammatical problems are very likely to be rejected as Too Minor.

Answer (score 13):

The suggested edit block was automatic due to a number of rejected edits, and has subsequently been lifted in the same manner - they expire in a week. It also appears that a few people who noticed your post here also noticed some of the better questions you asked on the main site, and up voted them. You'll be happy to know that the question block has also been lifted.

However - be careful going forward. Make sure your questions are clear, contain the best grammar and spelling you can manage and are formatted properly. You really need some up votes at this point in order to get a safe distance away from the block.

Good luck, and enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

> Why editing of questions(mine and others) is disabled in my account?

Probably you are banned for a week from suggesting edits as you have [13 rejected edits against 10 approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2087941). I think you should be enabled to edit your own post.

> It's a very long time closing of my "Ask Question"...

The asking ban will not be lifted without doing anything. You have to improve your previos posts. As you have deleted your questions, you have to undelete and improve them. For that flag one of your post and ask moderators to undelete your deleted questions.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed deleting many questions is considered "not a good thing". The system just sees this as vandalism - *"why is this user going around deleting lots of content?!?"*. It is true that sometimes you're actually *trying to do the right thing* but the system still sees your actions as potentially harmful to the community.

As others have already said, the systems here are **automatic** and there really isn't a person who is manually looking at your actions and deciding "ok, you've learnt your lesson". Posting this question here is indeed the correct thing to do in this instance. There is however lots of posts here on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) taking about the different types of bans and peoples recommendations on how to correct your behavior on the site.

In the same way that you've been a member of the site for over a year and *only now* the system has taken action, you'll have to work hard to make the system notice that you've changed your behavior. The *very best* thing that you can do is answer other peoples questions. This is one of the best ways to indicate to the system that you are **contributing to the community**. You've already got some votes and accepts for your existing answers so I trust that you know exactly how to **continue providing good content!**